# How to remove all lines with more than 3 slashes?

Tags: shell, url

I have a list of urls, some of them have paths after domain name and some of them don't.
I need to extract all urls that have nothing after the domain name.

Input:

```
https://youtube.com/user/
https://google.com/
https://twitter.com/home/
https://facebook.com/
```

Output:

```
https://google.com/
https://facebook.com/
```

Otherwise: how to remove everything after the 3rd occurrence of slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep can help you:

```
 grep  -v '[^/]/[^/]' file
```

To do the removing, `sed` can help:

```
sed 's#\([^/]\)/[^/].*#\1/#' file
```

> How to remove all lines with more than 3 slashes?

```
awk '{a=$0}gsub(/\//,"",a)<=3' file
```